# Logarithmic Equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the following logarithmic equation and I am getting stuck because the $x$ variable is cancelling out.

$\ln(x-5)-\ln(x+4)=\ln(x-1)-\ln(x+2)$

I made each term an exponent of $e$:

$e^{\ln(x-5)}-e^{\ln(x+4)}=e^{\ln(x-1)}-e^{\ln(x+2)}$

Then I used the product rule to separate the exponent from the base and also eliminated $e$ and $ln$ because they are equal to $1$:

$(x-5)-(x+4)=(x-1)-(x+2)$

Then I distributed the negative symbol and combined like terms to get

$-9=-3$

This is the point where I am lost.  The x variable cancelled out and I have no clue what went wrong or if this possibly right?  Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't make each individual term an exponent of $e$. You must make the whole left-hand side an exponent of $e$ and the whole right hand side as an exponent of $e$. You may also want to use the property $\log a - \log b = \log \frac{a}{b}$ before using the exponential.

Comment: How do you simplify $e^{a-b}$?

Comment: "I made each term an exponent of $e$" - There is your mistake. Rethink this step carefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note
$$\ln(x−5)−\ln(x+4)=\ln\frac{x-5}{x+4}$$
and
$$\ln(x−1)−\ln(x+2)=\ln\frac{x-1}{x+2}$$
so that
$$\ln\frac{x-5}{x+4}=\ln\frac{x-1}{x+2}$$
now you can exponentiate and get
$$\frac{x-5}{x+4}=\frac{x-1}{x+2}$$
and this is a quadratic that you know how to solve.

Comment: So when I multiply the left-hand side of the equation by the reciprocal of the right-hand side, and then multiply, I get the following: $\frac{ x^{2}-3x-10 }{ x^{2}+3x-4 }=0$. Then the x values will cancel out and a negative will remain in front of the fraction yielding: $- \frac{-10}{-4} $. Upon distributing that negative I get: $\frac{10}{4} $.  Shouldn't that be two solutions?

Comment: Nope, you get that equal to one, think about it.

Comment: I multiplied each side by the reciprocal and then multiplied on the left to get: $x^{4}-23x^{2}-18x+40=0$.  I feel like I just went in the wrong direction.  Any help?

Comment: It's much easier than that, forget about the reciprocal, look $$\frac{x−5}{x+4}=\frac{x−1}{x+2}$$ implies $$(x-5)(x+2)= (x-1)(x+4)$$ multiplying by $(x+2)(x+4)$ on both sides, now expand each side and sum everything on one side to get a quadratic

Comment: So performing those operations and then moving everything onto one side I get: $-6x-6=0$.  Then I factored to get: $-6(x+1)=0$.  Setting each term to zero yields $-6 \neq 0$ and $x=-1$. The first can't work and the second doesn't work because it is negative and you can't take the negative of a log.  So is the answer "No Solution"?

Comment: First, you don't have to set each term equal to zero, so forget about the $-6$. Second, we used the properties of the logarithm to show that even though $log(x-5)$ is not defined for negative arguments $log(x-5)+log(x-2)$ is. So if you require argument$>0$ for each logarithm the left hand side is only defined for $x\geq5$ and the right hand side for $x\geq2$ so there is no solution. But if you look carefully and use the properties there is. Anyway, I think the point of this exercise is just to teach you how to use the properties of the logarithm. So don't get confused by these issues.

Comment: Brilliant! It works! I finally understand what you mean.  If I take the original equation and move everything to the left side, I would get: $\ln(x-5)-\ln(x+4)-\ln(x-1)+\ln(x+2)=0$. Then by utilizing the  properties of logarithms a negative argument would work in this case.  The first two equations would simplify to: $\ln(-2)-\ln(-2)=0$. This yields $\ln(1)=0$, which is $0=0$!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot raise each term by itself.

Use the following rule instead:

$$\ln{a} - \ln{b} = \ln{\frac{a}{b}}$$

Your problem then simplifies to:

$$\ln{\frac{x-5}{x+4}} = \ln{\frac{x-1}{x+2}}$$

Then subtract both sides by the value on the right hand side and use the same rule again. The right hand side becomes 0, so the value inside the $\ln$-operator should equal 1. Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

A hint:

I there  are no errors in your calculation the meaning of you last line ist, that htere is no $x$ that solves the equation because the last euqation 
$$-9=-3$$
is false for all values of $x$.
But you made an error when you derived $e^{\ln(x-5)}-e^{\ln(x+4)}=e^{\ln(x-1)}-e^{\ln(x+2)}$
From $$\ln(x-5)-\ln(x+4)=\ln(x-1)-\ln(x+2)$$ follows

$$e^{\ln(x-5)-\ln(x+4)}=e^{\ln(x-1)-\ln(x+2)}$$

(why?) and from this follows what?

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the calculation:

$$x^{2} -3x -10 = x^{2} +3x -4$$
$$-6 = 6x$$
$$x = -1$$

But if you substitute the value in the original equation you obtain 
                       ln -2 = ln -2
which is valid only in the complex world.